# JQuery reference is not working in Orchard

Tags: jquery, orchardcms

Hi i added a jquery reference to a cshtml page in orchard module.but my alert message not working and no errors as well. i found few answers for the same issue but none of them works for me.So i appreciate your help on this.
I have added an entry to the Module.txt file as "Dependencies: Settings, Orchard.jQuery"
and my cshtml code looks like below :

```
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;

@{
   Script.Require("jQuery");
   Script.Require("jQueryUI");
  }
<div>
    <button name="click" id="btnClick">
     Click here
    </button>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>

@using(Script.Foot()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                alert("Hello");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: try having Script.Require("jQuery").AtFoot(); Although what you have should work, unless you are getting errors like missing a } at the end of the using(Script... but I guess that is just a copy typo

Comment: Have you ensured that the jQuery module is enabled in the admin?

Comment: This should most definitely work, which makes me think it's your template that is never hit. Put a breakpoint in there and attach a debugger, to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for giving me suggestions on this issue. I myself found what went wrong.I used a .cshtml view and once its rendered i checked the view source and it  didn't have header,body and footer tags.So the script was not attached.When the page is rendered through  a layout page the issue is solved :) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;

@{
Script.Include("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js").AtHead();

 Script.Include("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js").AtHead();
  }
<div>
    <button name="click" id="btnClick">
     Click here
    </button>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>

@using(Script.Foot()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
            $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                alert("Hello");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Omar ,but this does not work.I i really want to refer to the Orchard.Jquery module. if i refer to cdn repository it works well as <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>